# How do I promote PostgreSQL warnings to exceptions in psycopg2?

Tags: python, postgresql, warnings, psycopg2

From the PostgreSQL [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-begin.html) on `BEGIN`:

> Issuing BEGIN when already inside a transaction block will provoke a
>   warning message. The state of the transaction is not affected.

How can I make `psycopg2` raise an exception on any such warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am very far from being `psycopg2` or `Postgres` expert, and, I am sure there is a better solution to increase the warning level, but here is something that worked for me - [a custom cursor](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/advanced.html#subclassing-connection) which looks into [connection notices](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/connection.html#connection.notices) and, if there is something there - it throws an exception. The implementation itself is for education purposes mostly - I am sure it needs to be adjusted to work in your use case:

```
import psycopg2

# this "cursor" class needs to be used as a base for custom cursor classes
from psycopg2.extensions import cursor  

class ErrorThrowingCursor(cursor):
    def __init__(self, conn, *args, **kwargs):
        self.conn = conn
        super(ErrorThrowingCursor, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def execute(self, query, vars=None):
        result = super(ErrorThrowingCursor, self).execute(query, vars)

        for notice in self.conn.notices:
            level, message = notice.split(": ")
            if level == "WARNING":
                raise psycopg2.Warning(message.strip())

        return result
```

Usage sample:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(user="user", password="secret")
cursor = conn.cursor(conn, cursor_factory=ErrorThrowingCursor)
```

This would throw an exception (of a [`psycopg2.Warning`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/module.html#psycopg2.Warning) type) if a warning was issued after a query execution. Sample:

```
psycopg2.Warning: there is already a transaction in progress
```

Comment: This looks very clean. It'd we nice if `psycopg` supported such cursors out of the box though.